# Error:SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, git-clone

I'm coding in Android studio. I  cloned a project from gitHub

https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker

but I have this problem,

[image]

I don't know how to solve it because I'm new in android studio.

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace.

Comment: reformatting and corrected grammar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come across the same problem,here is how i fix it.Change the item `distributionUrl` of `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to your local gradle,detail see the picture below:

[image]

Comment: For me Gradle version is correct but still it is giving exact same error message whenever I run gradle refresh. I copied code form Mac Android Studio 2.3.3 to Windows Android Studio 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Using **http** at the beginning of the distributionUrl resolved it for me:

distributionUrl=**http**://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: http is not allowed, you have to force to use it.